# NSURLConnection help

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsurlconnection

Also I know that anything that I create using alloc I have to release it, but when I try to release 'request' object using [request release];  it throws the following error:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
kill
error while killing target (killing anyway): warning: error on line 2179 of "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1510/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c" in function "macosx_kill_inferior_safe": (os/kern) failure (0x5x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the request using `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`. Since that method name doesn't begin with "alloc" or "new" or contain "copy", according to the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) you don't own it and so should not be releasing it (unless you call retain on it explicitly, of course).

As for efficiency, the code seems fine. Note though that if the user can trigger a second load before the first completes that you will have problems; the solution to that is to either prevent such a thing or to save the NSURLConnection object created in `load` into an ivar and then have the pseudo-delegate methods check that against the passed connection before doing anything else. It's also a good idea to set the ivar to nil when you release the object it formerly contained, as then you cannot accidentally use the released object. And I note the variable name for your "authentication failed" alert is `alertsuccess`, that's misleading ;)

Comment: [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; wont this line consume any memory? Also is everything else fine as far as the coding goes or am I making any obvious mistakes one should not make for efficient coding?

Comment: `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]` will leak an object. I didn't mention it earlier because I saw you released it in `connection:didFailWithError:` (which, come to think of it, is probably poor form; store it in an ivar instead). Although now I notice you don't release it or responseData in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, which is certainly a problem.

Comment: i very much appreciate your help so far. I have tried to release connection and responseData in the connectionDidFinishLoading method. Edited my code above. Could you please show me if how to have pseudo-delegate method check connection. I have also updated the alertsuccess to alertfailure..

Comment: @developer: First you have to store the result of `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]` in an ivar. Then in each of the connection methods, right at the top insert `if (connection != savedConnection) return;`

Comment: what kind of ivar should i use. should it be something like below NSURLConnection *urlConnect=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; Also i am sorry for asking so many questions but this is my first screen of the app and i want it to be efficient so that i dont later on keep on repeating my mistakes..

Comment: @developer: No, that's a local variable. An ivar would be exactly what you did with responseData.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your load function:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;

request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pageUrl]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];`
```

NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithCString:[data bytes] length:[data length]];
`